# netbeans not recognizing ArrayUtil

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using the following statement

```
int[] numList = ArrayUtil.randomIntArray(100, 100);
```

and I have imported

```
import java.util.*;
```

so importing the right class is out of the question here. I'm trying to create an array of 100 numbers and populate the array with random numbers from 1-100, but netbeans is putting a red line under "ArrayUtil" I glance over it with my mouse to read the error "can not find symbol, Symbol: variable ArrayUtil" why is this happening when I have imported all needed classes

Thanks

Comment: Just because it has "Util" in the name doesn't mean that it's in `java.util`. It's _not_ in the Java SE library at all, in fact. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195219/arrayutil-causes-unexpected-error-in-java ?

Comment: so, I need to download the java EE + jdk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to download and import [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) if you want to use their Libraries. It is not part of the standard Java API.

Or create the function yourself;

```
public int[] randomIntArray(int length, int size) {
  Random r = new Random();
  int[] numbers = new int[length];
  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = r.nextInt(size+1);
  }
  return numbers;
}
```

Comment: which one do I install: proper, sandbox, dormant, or all of them?

Comment: If you only need it for this method then just use my implementation.

Answer (score 6):

You can download from [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/commons-lang/jars/commons-lang-2.3.jar)

The link is for commons lang 2.3