# ArrayUtils.reverse() Usage

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

What is the correct format for ArrayUtils.reverse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ArrayUtil causes unexpected error in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195219/arrayutil-causes-unexpected-error-in-java)

Comment: I could not find an clear answer in there.

Comment: what package is arrayutils? seems to be from Apache commons. Did you add that to your classpath?

Answer (score 3):

The error refers to the fact that `ArrayUtils` cannot be found among your classes, the standard Java runtime or the libraries in your classpath.

`ArrayUtils` is part of [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/), you need to include that jar library in your project and to add an `import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils` on top, to make this work.

Comment: How do I include the Apache Commons jar library in my project. I tried that import before but it gave me an error because of the jar library.

Comment: What do you mean by Editor? I am relatively new to Java.

Comment: You are really new i guess :) Where are you writing your code? Eclipse? Netbeans?

Comment: Do you mean JRE/JDK? I am running my program on Eclipse.

Comment: When I was following the link it asked me to Locate and select the "acm.jar" file you just downloaded, and then click "Open" and it wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

try `Collections.reverse(yourArrayList);`

for javadoc, [docs.oracle.com/...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List))